# Is it possible to solve for $x$ in $B = 0.16Y^{0.36}\cdot Z^{0.57} \cdot x^{0.032} \cdot \ln(1+17.5x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is possible to solve for $x$ in the following equation :
$B = 0.16Y^{0.36}\cdot Z^{0.57} \cdot x^{0.032} \cdot \ln(1+17.5x)$?

Will I require more information, can you provide some direction/solution?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting by editing in mathjax. Is this the equation you intended?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for the help

Comment: I would say no, it isn´t possible. Do you want just solve the equation for $x$ or it is just your intermediate step for calculating something else ?

Answer (score 2):

All the constants can be pulled into one, giving $A = x^{0.032} \cdot \ln(1+17.5x)$  You might find a solution using the Lambert W function, which is the tool of choice with mixed exponentials and polynomials (exponentiate both sides to get there), but are likely stuck with a numeric solution.  Your function is [nicely monotonic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E0.032*log(1%2B17.5x)%20from%200%20to%202), so any root finder should have no problem.
[image]